# /builtin command and ; semicolon in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have tried to understand this paragraph of shell script but it is so difficutl to me.

```
build_dicts_script=`\builtin cd $T; build/soong/soong_ui.bash --dumpvars-mode \
                        --vars="$cached_vars" \
                        --abs-vars="$cached_abs_vars" \
                        --var-prefix=var_cache_ \
                        --abs-var-prefix=abs_var_cache_`

eval "$build_dicts_script"
```

What is the role of "\builtin" and ";" in this paragraph ? Can someone explain for me about it ? Thank so much !

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `make`. You should probably remove the `makefile` tag.

Comment: Be aware, that appears to be a *terrible* use of the `eval` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`builtin cmd` executes the `cmd` builtin of the shell instead of any other `cmd` command, alias, function... that could exist in the current scope. `\builtin` guarantees that it is the `builtin` builtin that is executed, not an alias with the same name. So, `\builtin cd $T` changes the current directory to the current value of shell variable `T` using the `cd` builtin of the shell.

The `;` between the two commands of the script chains them as a sequence. The first command is executed, then the second. Other chaining operators are:

- `&&` to execute the second command only of the first one succeeded (exited with a zero exit status).
- `||` to execute the second command only of the first one fails (exited with a non-zero exit status).
- `|` to pipe the standard output of the first command to the standard input of the second.

Comment: In this case, What is different between using ```cd``` and ```\builtin cd``` ?

Comment: The answer explains exactly this already. If `cd` is an alias or function, `builtin cd` bypasses the alias. If `builtin` is an alias, `\builtin` bypasses the alias.